# Microsoft Graph API calls from Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a fairly simple task. I need to be able to create draft messages in my Outlook account from Python. I understand this entails registering an app in the Azure Active Directory and setting the respective permissions - that I have done. My problem is in logging in from Python - I cannot figure out how to do it. I know there are sample scripts for various avenues of doing so but they did not help me. I do not need any complicated web pages created with Flask, I just have to login and make a simple graph api call.

If you could show a bare-bones example of logging in from Python I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can start with this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app) which uses Device code flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple demo that creating a mail draft for a certain Azure AD user, try the code below:

```
import adal
import json
import requests

tenant = '<your tenant name or id>'
app_id = '<your azure ad app id>'
app_password = '<your azure ad app secret>'
userAccount = '<user account you want to create mail draft>'

resource_URL ='https://graph.microsoft.com'
authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s'%(tenant)

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource_URL,
    app_id,
    app_password)

request_headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer %s'%(token['accessToken'])}

create_message_URL =resource_URL + '/v1.0/users/%s/messages'%(userAccount)

message_obj = {
    "subject":"Did you see last night's game?",
    "importance":"Low",
    "body":{
        "contentType":"HTML",
        "content":"They were <b>awesome</b>!"
    },
    "toRecipients":[
        {
            "emailAddress":{
                "address":"AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}

result = requests.post(create_message_URL, json = message_obj,headers = request_headers)

print(result.text)
```

Result:
[image]

Note: please make sure that your Azure AD application has been granted with the application `Mail.ReadWrite` permission
[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.